# IOS Launch screen storyboard shows up in different orientation

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode11, launch-screen

I have an IOS app built with XCODE 11 which is landscape only(right+left).We are trying to move from Legacy launch images to Story board Launch screen.

The issue seems to be that the new launch screen appears as expected in landscape mode but when the device is in portrait orientation, the launch screen also appears in portrait , which looks weird because the image is meant to be in landscape to match the app orientation.

Note: The app launches in landscape after the launch screen irrespective of how the device is held.

**Is there a way to lock the launch screen orientation to match the app (Landscape left+right)?**

Been stuck on this issue for a while, appreciate any inputs :)

Comment: same issue.. xcode 11

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set Supported interface orientations landscape in your info.plist only ?

Comment: Hi @King.lbt , yes i have the supported orientations in my plist as below
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
 </array>

The app works fine, the issue is with the launch screen orientation